# Android SAXParser using Simple Framework

Tags: android, xml

I want to parse a xml: http://www.sjc.com.vn/xml/tygiavang.xml
The item i want to get is:  buy="32.800" sell="33.070" type="Vàng SJC 1L" and updated time

I use Simple Framework to parse but i can not get the element i want.
Here is my class:
ratelist.java

```
   @Root(name = "ratelist", strict = false)
public class Ratelist{
   @Attribute
    private String updated;

   @Element
    private String city;

    public String getUpdated(){
        return updated;
    }
    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

}
```

city.java

```
  @Root(name = "city", strict = false)
public class City {
    @Attribute
    private String name;

    @Element
    private String item;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getItem(){
        return item;
    }

}
```

item.java

```
 @Root(name = "item", strict = false)
public class Item {
   @Attribute
    private String buy;

    @Attribute
    private String sell;

    @Attribute
    private String type;

    public String getBuy(){
        return buy;
    }
    public String getSell(){
        return sell;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
}
```

Roo_class.java

```
@Root
public class Root_class {
    @Element
    private String title;

    @Element
    private String url;

    @Element
    private Ratelist ratelist;

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        return url;
    }

    public Ratelist getRatelist(){
        return ratelist;
    }

}
```

and the main.java

```
public class main extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    String path = "http://www.sjc.com.vn/xml/tygiavang.xml";
    MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data_listview = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String ngay;
    String mua = "";
    String ban = "";
    String loai = "";
    TextView tv_ban, tv_mua, tv_loai, tv_ngay;
    Item item;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city_gold, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        tv_ban = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv_mua = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv_loai = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv_ngay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

        tv_ban.setText(R.string.sell);
        tv_mua.setText(R.string.buy);
        tv_loai.setText(R.string.type);

        if (isNetworkConnected()==true) {
            myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
            myAsyncTask.execute();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.requirenetwork, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        if (isNetworkConnected() == true) {
                            myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
                            myAsyncTask.execute();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        if (isNetworkConnected() == false) {
                            snackbar();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            data_listview.clear();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.updating), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.wait));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                URL url = new URL(path);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                Serializer serializer = new Persister();
                Ratelist data = serializer.read(Ratelist.class, is);


                    ban = item.getSell() + "\n";
                    mua = item.getBuy() + "\n";
                    loai = item.getType() + "\n";
                    //
                    HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashmap.put("KEY_ID", ban);
                    hashmap.put("KEY_NAME", mua);
                    hashmap.put("KEY_BUY", loai);
                    data_listview.add(hashmap);

              //  ngay = data.get();
               /* InputStream is2 = connection.getInputStream();
                Serializer serializer1=new Persister();
                ratelist data1=serializer1.read(ratelist.class,is2);
                for (ratelist ratelist:data1.getCity()){

                }*/

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String text = getResources().getString(R.string.update);
            tv_ngay.setText(text + ": " + ngay);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                    data_listview, //du lieu
                    R.layout.currency_mot_item,  //lay out
                    new String[]{"KEY_ID", "KEY_NAME", "KEY_BUY"}, //from
                    new int[]{R.id.textView10, R.id.textView11, R.id.textView12});  //to
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ban, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `serializer.read(Ratelist.class, is)` but `<ratelist>` isn't the root of the XML.

Make another class `Root` with the title, url, and ratelist elements, use that in the call to `serializer.read()`, and you should be all set.

Also, you aren't using the annotations correctly and accounting for repeating tags by using lists.

```
@Root(name="root")
public class Root {

    @Element
    private String title;

    @Element
    private String url;

    @Element
    private Ratelist ratelist;

    public Ratelist getRatelist() {
        return ratelist;
    }
}


@Element(name="ratelist")
public class Ratelist {

    @Attribute
    private String updated;

    @ElementList
    private List<City> cities;

    public String getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
}


@Element(name="city")
public class City {

    @Attribute
    private String name;

    @ElementList
    private List<Item> items;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}


@Element(name="item")
public class Item {

    @Attribute
    private String buy;

    @Attribute
    private String sell;

    @Attribute
    private String type;

    public String getBuy() {
        return buy;
    }

    public String getSell() {
        return sell;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

    InputStream is2 = connection.getInputStream();
    Serializer serializer1 = new Persister();
    Root root = serializer1.read(Root.class, is2);
    Ratelist ratelist = root.getRatelist();

    Log.d(TAG, "Updated: " + ratelist.getUpdated());

    for (City city : ratelist.getCities()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "City: " + city.getName());

        for (Item item : city.getItems()) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Buy: " + item .getBuy());
           Log.d(TAG, "Sell: " + item .getSell());
           Log.d(TAG, "Type: " + item .getType());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have created a Root class. You can see it on 1st post. But i dont know how to parse them. Can you show me the right thing